# How to get `Content-length` of response php cURL

Tags: php, curl

I try to write simple parser on php, with can give me only content-length of html page. For now I have this Code :

```
$urls = array(
    'http://Link1.com/',
    'http://Link2.com'
);

 $mh = curl_multi_init();     
 $connectionArray = array();
        foreach($urls as $key => $url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
            $connectionArray[$key] = $ch;
        }
        $running = null;
        do
        {
            curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        }while($running > 0);

        foreach($connectionArray as $key => $ch)
        {
            $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
            echo $content."<br>";
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
        }

        curl_multi_close($mh);
```

How can I get `Content-Length` from $content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) which returns:

> Content length of download, read from Content-Length: field

In this particular case, `-1` seems to be a [valid response](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD.html):

> Since 7.19.4, this returns -1 if the size isn't known.

Comment: I tried to use this `$info = curl_getinfo($content, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);` not worked.

Comment: I got just `<br><br>` without any results.

Comment: You should use `$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);` instead.

Comment: strange, but now I get `-1<br>-1<br>`

Comment: @Сергей could you please also check `$info = curl_getinfo($mh, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180671/discussion-between-fabrik-and-).

Comment: what do you mean `size isn't known.` how can this happen ? Сan I get html content and size this ?

Comment: If it isn't specified explicitly, you cannot get it, e.g. when response data is streamed to client. See linked cURL page in my answer.